# tryi to implement by my self a doubly linked list; calling afficheList() twice i get an infinity-loop?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, doubly-linked-list

would u like to read my code and tell me where i messed up ( i expect afficheList(List list) to print elements of list ) ? on the very right of my implemenation i wrotte how i understand my code tell me if i think wrong  i was told often there are difference between wht u want the computer to do and wht u tell it to do 
also i wonder if i should keep "trying and error". i am afraid of memory leak ! as i use dynamic memory allocation

watching video and reading on how to do doubly linked list haven't helped me so far; their implemetation seems to be too sophisticated for my little brain to understand

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


/* dans ce fichier je tente de creer une structure d'une liste doublement chainé avec quelques methodes de base que j'y associe
tel que creer une liste, la supprimer, cree un element la suppremer, ajouter un element à la liste et afficher la liste.
les commentation aux dessus de chaque implementation sont les eventuels documentation quan dà  ceux sur les côtes ;  ma vision
de l'implemetation : ceux à  quoi je m'attends qu elle fasse !
*/




// je renome structure Element en elt
// ca me set dans la declaration des structures, elle m'eviter de reécrire  " struct Element" et aussis
//ca m'aide personnellement dans la comprehension des structures !
typedef struct Element elt;

//declaration de la structure Element
struct Element{
    int val;
    elt* next;                                          // pointeur vers l'element d'apres
    elt* prev;                                          //  - -    -   -    -    - d'avant
};

//declaration de la structure list
struct List{
    elt* first;                                         //un pointeur vers un elemnt qui
                                                        // qui saure  le premier element de
                                                        // de la liste
};
/**cree un element à partir d'un entier
*@param un entier
*@return un pointeur à un element
**/
elt* creeElement(int nb){
    Element *res= new Element;                           // j'allou  une memoire pouvant contenir un
                                                         // un element, j'y accede avec le pointer res
    res->val = nb;                                       // ds la memoire, ds la partie val j'y met le param nb
    res->next = nullptr;                                 // dans next je met null
    res->prev = nullptr;                                 // dans prev je met null
    return res;                                          // je retourne l'adress pointé par le pointeur *res
}
/* libere la memoire d'un pointeur  passe en param*/
void deleElement(Element *el){
    delete[] el;                                         // soit un pointeur *el,je libère l'addr mémo pointé
}
/**cree une liste
*@param un pointeur à un element
**/


List* creeList(Element *el){
    List *res = new List;
                                                       // vers un element (first)) je pointe cette mémo avec *res
    res->first = el;                                   // je fais pointé first vers l'adresse du pointeur *el
    return res;                                        // je retourne l'addr mémo du pointeur  *res;
}

/** affiche une liste
*@param un pointeur à une list
**/
void afficheList(List *l){

    Element *el = new Element;                        // pointeur *el pointe vers une mémo dispoé à contenir un elememnt
    el = l->first;                                    // je pointe à first par le pointeur *el
    cout << " {"<<el->val<<"} ";                      // j'affiche le champs val de *el
    while (el->next != nullptr){                      // tant que le pointeur *next de l'element actuel n'est pas null;
        el = el->next;                                // l'elemnt next devient l'element actuel ( par le pointeur el )
        cout << " {"<<el->val <<"} ";                 // j'affiche l'element actuel
    }
    cout << " {"<<el->next <<"} ";
    delete el;                                        // je libère le memoire occupé par le pointeur *el;
}
/** ajoute un element sur une liste
*@param un pointeur à un element et un ptr à une liste
*/
void ajouteElement(List *l, Element *el){
    Element *tempo = l->first;
    while (tempo->next != nullptr){
        tempo = tempo->next;
    }
    el->prev = tempo;
    tempo->next = el;
}

//debut d'echecs
void deleteList( List *l){
    Element *actuel=nullptr;
    Element *next=nullptr;
    actuel = l->first;

    //ca me fait une boucle infini :(
    while(actuel->next != nullptr){
        next = actuel->next;
        delete[] actuel;
        actuel = next;

    }

    delete[] next;

}

void pop_back_List(List *l){
    Element *cible;
    cible = l->first;
    while(cible->next != nullptr){
        cible = cible->next;
    }
    delete[] cible;
}



int main()
{
    cout << "Hello List!" << endl;
    Element *el = creeElement(10);
    List *l = creeList(el);
    ajouteElement(l, creeElement(-2));
    ajouteElement(l, creeElement(12));


    cout <<" list :  " ;
    afficheList(l);
    cout <<" list 1:  " ;
    afficheList(l);

    return 0;
}
```

i expected 
list : {10} {-2} {12}  
list1 : {10} {-2} {12} 
instead i got an infinity loop :(

Comment: Individual objects that are instantiated in dynamic scope using `new` are destroyed using `delete` and not `delete[]`.

Answer (score 2):

First, C++ is not Java or C#, et'al. Keep that in mind. That said, you're allocating a new node with this code, then *immediately* leaking that allocation with the very next line:

```
Element *el = new Element; // el points to new node
el = l->first; // el points to head sentinal, node from above leaked
```

Then, you use `el` to  walk down the linked list, eventually reaching what you hope is the last node. Once that happens, you break the loop, but then you do this:

```
delete el; // delete last node in the list
```

At this point you've deleted a node from the actual list, The initial allocation made on the first line is long-gone (leaked), and now you've deleted a node from the list (the last node), but the pointer *in the list* that referred to that node still retains the original address (which is now defunct; it is a *dangling pointer*).

Executing the function again will reach that defunct dangling pointer, attempt to follow it, and invoke undefined behavior in the process.

Two things to correct this. First, this function shouldn't be modifying the list in the first place, so don't let it. Be `const` correct and pass the `List` pointer as `const`. Second, don't allocate, or delete, memory in this function *at all*.

```
void afficheList(List const *l) {

    Element const *el = l->first;
    cout << " {" << el->val << "} ";
    while (el->next != nullptr) 
    {
        el = el->next;
        cout << " {" << el->val << "} ";
    }
    cout << " {" << el->next << "} ";
}
```

That's it. there is still plenty of other things odd/wrong with this code, but this is the biggest problem with `afficheList`

Comment: thank you for taking  your time to correct me :) `afficheList` now works well :). if u can feel free to tell me about those **other  odd/wrong things** with this code @WhozCraig